# Set timeout function weirdly overlaps with useEffect hook containing a cleanup? Image Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

Hello I am trying a beginner react project where I'm building a review app with carousel functionality.
I've been able to get the logic right for static switch between reviews using the useEffect hook and a setInterval function however I also want the user to be able to manually move between reviews and this is where I'm stuck because it causes the setInterval function to overlap and causes weird behaviour. I've tried adding a cleanup which clears the interval on re-render but that doesn't work. Here is my code so far:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./style.css";
import { Data } from "../data/index";
import { Review } from "../review/index";

export const App = () => {
  const entries = [...Data]; //reviews data contains imgs,title, etc

  const [currentReview, setCurrentReview] = useState(0); //when updated re-renders the app to new review

  const updateReview = () => { //callback for setinterval
    if (currentReview === entries.length - 1) {
      setCurrentReview(0);
    } else {
      setCurrentReview(currentReview + 1);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(updateReview, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(updateReview, 3000);
    };
  });

  const previous = () => {
    if (currentReview === 0) {
      setCurrentReview(entries.length - 1);
    } else {
      setCurrentReview(currentReview - 1);
    }
  };

  const next = () => {
    if (currentReview === entries.length - 1) {
      setCurrentReview(0);
    } else {
      setCurrentReview(currentReview + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className="main">
      <button className="btn left" onClick={previous}> //svg for left facing arrow
        <svg
          stroke="currentColor"
          fill="none"
          stroke-width="2"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          height="1em"
          width="1em"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <polyline points="15 18 9 12 15 6"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </button>


      <Review props={entries[currentReview]} /> //Review component


      <button className="btn right" onClick={next}> //svg for right facing arrow
        <svg
          stroke="currentColor"
          fill="none"
          stroke-width="2"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          stroke-linecap="round"
          stroke-linejoin="round"
          height="1em"
          width="1em"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <polyline points="9 18 15 12 9 6"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </main>
  );
};
```

Here is the github repo for the project if you need anymore info: https://github.com/sumdude65/review_slider

Comment: Where i say setInterval, i mean both setInterval and setTimeout. I've used both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clearTimeout`'s argument must be the *timeout ID* that gets returned from the previous `setTimeout` call, not the function:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(updateReview, 3000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  });
```

Comment: Thanks alot for clearing this up for me. I have to wait a bit before i can accept your answer. I also want a slide-in from the right effect when a new review gets rendered. Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: You'll probably want a CSS transition, but I'm not very knowledgeable in it, sorry

Comment: i suspected that would be the case